# How do I create a bookmarklet to hide a specific page element?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm a total noob with bookmarklets. Can anyone help me with the code I need to put in my bookmark URL to hide this specific page element?

```
<div id="snigel-cmp-framework" class="snigel-cmp-framework" style="height: 722px;">
```

[image: Element I want to hide]

It's for a website I access a lot with a super annoying/aggressive cookie policy. You have to click a million checkboxes to opt out, and your preferences are erased when you close your browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple javascript, you just need to make it a one liner, and add`javascript:` as href of the link you shall drag to your bookmark bar to become bookmarklet. As for the code itself, it's pretty simple.

```html
<a href='javascript:var elem = document.querySelector("#snigel-cmp-framework"); elem && elem.remove()'>Drag me to bookmark bar</a>
```